# Programmatically changing the radius of a circle shape drawable

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, shapes

I have this shape in a file named `cercle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:height="1dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"/>
</shape>
```

I want to put it around an image and make its radius bigger or smaller programmatically:

```
ImageView closestImg = (ImageView) v.findViewWithTag(closest.getId().toString()); // I get my image like this, it works

ShapeDrawable circle= new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape());
circle.setIntrinsicHeight(60);
circle.setIntrinsicWidth(60);
circle.setBounds(new Rect(30, 30, 30, 30));
circle.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#FCFF00"));

closestImg.setBackground(circle);
```

This solution works to put the circles around (behind) my image.
But now I want to be able to change the radius of the circle.

How can I do this?